# How to add location to a post or a photo with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, location, facebook-php-sdk, photo

This is driving me nuts.

Can anyone post a *practical* example on this? My gratitude for life:

1. Publish a post and add the related checkin/location info
2. publish a photo and add the related checkin/location info.

In both cases the user delegates the action to the app. We have the access token by prior.

Please no theory, a working coding snipper ;-)

I am particularly messed up because facebook asks a nested structures of *objects* and *arrays*

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the `$user` instance

```php
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Check if the logged in user is authenticated.

```php
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed 
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Present the login url with permissions needed for posting. Specifically the `publish_stream`permission as stated in the photo documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

```php
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
             'scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos'
             ));
}
```

Place the `me/photos` call in a try/catch block to catch any exceptions that may occur.

```php
    try {
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport('http://yourapicallingwebsite.com/');
        $response = $facebook->api(
          '/me/photos/',
          'post',
          array(
            'message' => 'Testing the Photo Upload',
            'source' => '@/path/to/img',
            'place' => 'place_id' 
          )
        );
      }
   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       error_log('An error occurred posting the image');
   }
```

Check the response from the me/photos call

```php
$photo_u = $facebook->api('/'.$response['id']);
```

Display it if your like

```php
<img src=<?php echo $photo_u['picture'] ?>/>
```

Check the place name if you like

```php
$photo_place = $photo_u['place'];
<span><?php echo $photo_place['name'] ?></span>
```